# DS4 Controller forgets pairing - PC and PS4

Tags: pc, ps4, controllers

I think my controller has died, but I thought I'd throw the problem out there in case anyone might have any tricks I haven't tried yet.

I have a DS4 controller, that once paired works fine. The battery is good and it stays paired all the time it is powered on. If however I power off the controller by any means - turn off the PS4, hold the PS button down for 10 seconds, or go into settings and turn off device - the controller will fail to turn back and will be completely dead for a minute or so. Eventually, pressing the PS button on the controller will make the light flash white 6 times, but it is basically no longer paired.

I can repair it by using a USB cable, or holding the PS button and share buttons together until the light strobes white, and going into bluetooth devices, and it then works fine again until I turn it off.

If I turn it off briefly, it will reconnect ok, but only if the controller is off for less than 3 seconds or so - If it is off for 5 seconds, it becomes lifeless as I have described above.

The same behaviour is shown when I pair it to the PC. I've downloaded DS4Windows, and it works fine until I turn the controller off.

I've pressed the reset button on the back, and have disconnected the internal battery - none of which have fixed it. The battery would appear to be working fine - it holds it's charge.

Anything else I could try?

Ta